# Error in cv.lars in R

Tags: r, lasso-regression, lars

I have a question regarding the **cv.lars**. Bellow there is a description for the data I use:

```
is.numeric(Y$Y1)
[1] TRUE

length(Y$Y1)
[1] 589


dim(Training_XX[7:ncol(Training_XX)])
[1]  589 5677
```

I have already run **lasso** using **lars** package. My code is as follows:

```
LASSO_1<-lars(as.matrix(X[7:ncol(X)]), 
              Y$Y1,type=c("lasso"), 
              normalize=TRUE, use.Gram=FALSE).
```

The above procedure seems to run fine. However, when I'm trying to **cross-validate** for the **lambda** value, I get the following error:

```
Error in if (zmin < gamhat) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

My code for the cross-validation is:

```
CV<-cv.lars(as.matrix(X[7:ncol(X)]),Y$Y1,use.Gram=FALSE,max.steps=500)
lambda_Y1=CV$index[which.min(CV$cv)]
```

Does anyone has any idea what's going on? I really don't know what that error means and what's wrong with my data (and or code).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but try using [glmnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmnet/index.html), instead. It's got the lasso (as a special case of the elasticnet), and is much faster.

Comment: You are so right!!! I didn't think about it...

Comment: I just set a=1 and I get lasso, is that right?
Do you now if the glmnet lasso and lars lasso give same or very similar results (they should)?
And the computational time...lars takes so long!!GLMNET is very fast
Thank you so much!

Comment: Read the docs in `?glmnet`, it is quite specific about the value of `alpha` required to get the lasso. Also, about the similarity between the two algorithms, this can also be easily verified with a few small test examples. It's not that I do not want to answer your questions, but when it's easy to answer them yourself, you should prefer that over trusting some random person over the internet, like me. Enjoy the new found speed! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, and the problem (at least in my case) was that two columns of my data matrix were equal. It seems lars doesn't handle this well. Just filter columns with very high correlation.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I forgot to scale my predictor variables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).